# Erro em programa C compatibilidade entre ponteiro para float e float

Tags: c

Preciso passar um **vetor de float** para uma função que aloca dinamicamente a memória e depois retorna esse vetor invertido. Entrentanto, meu código me diz que tenho um erro aqui:

programa.c: In function 'reverse':

programa.c:13:9: error: incompatible types when returning type 'float *' but 'float' was expected
  return novo;

Eu entendo qual o erro, mas não consigo entender como alocar memória e transformar esse vetor em float. Quando faço a alocação o programa me retorna um ponteiro para float.

Como vou fazer essa conversão ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float reverse(float* v, int n ) {
    float *novo;
    novo = (float *) malloc (n * sizeof(float));
    if (novo == NULL) {printf("Falta memoria\n"); exit(1);}
    for(int i = 0,j = n -i -1 ; i < j ;i++, j--) {
        int tmp = v[i]; 
        v[i] = novo[j]; 
        novo[j] = tmp;    
    }
    return novo;
}

void printFloatArray(float *v, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%1.6f  ",v[i]);
    }
}


int main(void) {
    float *novo;
    float v[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    printf("Vetor original:\n");
    printFloatArray(v,10);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Vetor invertido:\n");
    reverse(v,10);
    printFloatArray(novo,10);
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, a declaração da sua função `reverse` deveria ser:

```
float* reverse(float* v, int n)
```

Pois nela você pretende retornar algo do tipo ponteiro para float, que vai indicar o endereço de memória de seu novo vetor.

Em seguida, na função `main`, você deveria atualizar a variável `novo` para receber o valor retornado pela função `reverse`, asim:

```
novo = reverse(v,10);
```

Perceba que sem isso você não estará alterando o valor dela em lugar algum da função `main`.
A variável `novo` que está na função `reverse` é outra pois está num **escopo** diferente.
Você precisar fazer a atribuição com o valor retornado para efetivar essa ligação.

Por último, a lógica de reversão dentro do for está incorreta. Se você usar um iterador do começo para o final e outro do final para o começo, poderá usá-los para indexar e fazer a correta atribuição em cada posição do novo vetor com o respectivo valor do vetor antigo.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você está com dúvida quanto ao retorno da sua função `float reverse(float* v, int n )`, que poderia ser assim: `float *reverse(float* v, int n ) {`. Mas particularmente eu faria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *allocFloatArray(int numberOfPositions){

    float *pointer;

    pointer = (float *) malloc (numberOfPositions * sizeof(float));

    if (pointer == NULL) { printf("Falta memoria\n");  exit(1); }

    return pointer;
}

void reverse(float* v, float* novo, int n) {

    for(int i = 0, j = n - 1; 
        i < n;
        i++, j--) {

        novo[j] = v[i];  
    }
}

void printFloatArray(float *v, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%1.6f  ",v[i]);
    }
}


int main(void) {

    float *novo;

    novo = allocFloatArray(10);

    float v[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    printf("Vetor original:\n");

    printFloatArray(v,10);

    printf("\n");

    printf("Vetor invertido:\n");

    reverse(v, novo, 10);

    printFloatArray(novo,10);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Dessa forma, eu alloco um array de float do tamanho que quiser, atribuo o endereço de memória desse vetor pra minha variável na função principal (`novo = allocFloatArray(10);`) e utilizo outra função para passar os valores de forma invertida. Deixando cada função com uma responsabilidade bem definida.

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer coisa, estamos ai.